# How do I check/uncheck all checkboxes with a button using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I am trying to check/uncheck all checkboxes using jQuery. Now by checking/unchecking the parent checkbox all the child checkboxes are getting selected/deselected also with the text of parent checkbox getting changed to checkall/uncheckall.

Now I want to replace parent checkbox with an input button, and change the text also on the button to checkall/uncheckall. THere is the code, can anyone please tweak the code ?

```
    $( function() {
        $( '.checkAll' ).live( 'change', function() {
            $( '.cb-element' ).attr( 'checked', $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'checked' : '' );
            $( this ).next().text( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ? 'Uncheck All' : 'Check All' );
        });
        $( '.cb-element' ).live( 'change', function() {
            $( '.cb-element' ).length == $( '.cb-element:checked' ).length ? $( '.checkAll' ).attr( 'checked', 'checked' ).next().text( 'Uncheck All' ) : $( '.checkAll' ).attr( 'checked', '' ).next().text( 'Check All' );

        });
    });


   <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> <b>Check All</b>

   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Try this one :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/Vj6wY/3/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, working like a charm prakash. But how do we toggle the text on button also checkall/uncheck..

Comment: @Prakash +1 for best solution, but why u use `$(this).val('check all');` any specific reason??

Comment: It will the the Text of the button :)

Comment: @Prakash, but that is already defined, i think that line is not necessary

Comment: @prakash I have implemented your logic onto my datagrid, but have one last issue :(. I dont want all the checkboxes on the datagrid to be selected but only the checkboxes in the childrows which are having class of [class^=child1-]. So how i target only those TR's. Here is my data grid demo [Data Grid](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/UZtSx/4/)

Comment: @nahom try this selector `$('tr[class^=child1] input:checkbox').toggle()` , ie checkbox within tr having class starting with 'class1'. if it doesn't help, post the html that have been generate to help you further.

Comment: @prakash I have tried using the above selector, but no luck. Here is the html demo that i have been working on. Please take a look at it. http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/UZtSx/5/

Comment: -1 as toggle is not meant for working like that: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/ (at least the current version)

Comment: Only works for one button, if you need several it is best to use `.click()`

Comment: **Heads up: this answer checks literally every checkbox in your form.**  Skip unless you want that.  For multiple checkalls this answer helped me:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27148382/3448554

Comment: I tried this code, but why does my checkbox disappears ? xD and it has a "display:none" property on it

Comment: This will not work anymore, .toggle(handler, handler) was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. Now all it does is toggles visibility.

Comment: With the newest versions of jQuery, `.attr()` and `removeAttr()` shouldn't be used with the "checked" attribute. As `removeAttr()` will remove the attribute instead of setting it to `false`. `.prop('checked', true)` or `.prop('checked', false)` should be used instead, as explained in @richard-garside answer.

Answer (score 130):

This is the shortest way I've found (needs jQuery1.6+)

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>
```

JS:

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

I'm using .prop as .attr doesn't work for checkboxes in jQuery 1.6+ unless you've explicitly added a checked attribute to your input tag.

Example-

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: How do you use this one? Any chance of seeing a fiddle?

Comment: Simple answer, but OP wanted a button

Comment: How do you "deselect all" in this way?

Comment: @MichalSkop This code selects or deselects based on whether the #checkAll is checked or not. If you want to uncheck all then you can just use the value false like this $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', false);

Comment: Thanks, very easy!

Answer (score 23):

Try This One:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="checkall" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('#checkall:checkbox').change(function () {
   if($(this).attr("checked")) $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
   else $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xHCwJ/)

Comment: Yes thanks this code perfect, even if it changes from DOM LEVEL.
I have been tried hard to code, but even i tried other plugins that too are not working.. This one is perfect.

Answer (score 15):

Html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="select_all" id="select_all" class="checkAll" />
```

Javascript

```
    $('.checkAll').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
    }
    else{
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Use .prop instead of .attr if you're using jQuery1.6+

Answer (score 8):

Solution for toggling checkboxes using a button, compatible with jQuery 1.9+ where [toogle-event is no longer available](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/):

```
$('.check:button').click(function(){
      var checked = !$(this).data('checked');
      $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', checked);
      $(this).val(checked ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all' )
      $(this).data('checked', checked);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/1611/)

Comment: Replaced the button with a checkbox and "input:checkbox" with a class, for my purposes, and this worked great!

Answer (score 8):

**Check / Uncheck All with Intermediate property using jQuery**

Get Checked Items in Array using **getSelectedItems()** method

**Source [Checkbox List Select / Unselect All with Indeterminate Master Check](http://www.freakyjolly.com/jquery-checkbox-list-select-unselect-all-with-indeterminate-master-check-example-tutorial/)**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="selectAll"
            id="masterCheck"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="masterCheck">
            Select / Unselect All
          </label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush" id="list-wrapper">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item1"
            id="item1"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item1">
            Item 1
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item2"
            id="item2"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item2">
            Item 2
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item3"
            id="item3"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item3">
            Item 3
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item4"
            id="item4"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item4">
            Item 4
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <input
            class="form-check-input"
            type="checkbox"
            value="item5"
            id="item5"
          />
          <label class="form-check-label" for="item5">
            Item 5
          </label>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item" id="selected-values"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $(function() {
    // ID selector on Master Checkbox
    var masterCheck = $("#masterCheck");
    // ID selector on Items Container
    var listCheckItems = $("#list-wrapper :checkbox");

    // Click Event on Master Check
    masterCheck.on("click", function() {
      var isMasterChecked = $(this).is(":checked");
      listCheckItems.prop("checked", isMasterChecked);
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    // Change Event on each item checkbox
    listCheckItems.on("change", function() {
      // Total Checkboxes in list
      var totalItems = listCheckItems.length;
      // Total Checked Checkboxes in list
      var checkedItems = listCheckItems.filter(":checked").length;

      //If all are checked
      if (totalItems == checkedItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", true);
      }
      // Not all but only some are checked
      else if (checkedItems > 0 && checkedItems < totalItems) {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", true);
      }
      //If none is checked
      else {
        masterCheck.prop("indeterminate", false);
        masterCheck.prop("checked", false);
      }
      getSelectedItems();
    });

    function getSelectedItems() {
      var getCheckedValues = [];
      getCheckedValues = [];
      listCheckItems.filter(":checked").each(function() {
        getCheckedValues.push($(this).val());
      });
      $("#selected-values").html(JSON.stringify(getCheckedValues));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$('.checkAll').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.cb-element').prop('checked', $(e.target).prop('checked'));
});
```

`e` is the event generated when you do `click`,  and `e.target` is the element clicked (`.checkAll`),
so you only have to put the property `checked` of elements with class `.cb-element` like that of element
with class .checkAll`.

PS: Excuse my bad English!

Comment: Hey Ruben, you should add a comment to your answer so that the OP can understand how you solved that problem exactly

Comment: Thanks for your help @edi9999, I am a beginner

Comment: This answer is better IMO since **the accepted answer will check all checkboxes on your form**, while your pattern let's you easily target different HTML form *$("#id")* or *$(".class")* elements via a pattern like  ```$('#all_news_items').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.news-item-option').prop('checked', $(e.target).prop('checked'));
 });```   without the checkall functions interferring with other form elements, so you can add a new checkall easily: ```$('#all_specializations').on('click', function(e) {
     $('.specialization-option').prop('checked', $(e.target).prop('checked'));
 });```

Answer (score 4):

Below code will work if user select all checkboxs then check all-checkbox will be checked and if user unselect any one checkbox then check all-checkbox will be unchecked.

```js
$("#checkall").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});

$(".cb-element").change(function () {
  if($(".cb-element").length==$(".cb-element:checked").length)
    $("#checkall").prop('checked', true);
  else
    $("#checkall").prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="all" id="checkall" />Check All</br>

<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2</br>
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

Answer (score 4):

Agreed with Richard Garside's short answer, but instead of using `prop()` in `$(this).prop("checked")` you can use native JS `checked` property of [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox) like,

```js
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#">
    <p><label><input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> Check all</label></p>
    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Loads of checkboxes</legend>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 1</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 2</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 3</label></p>
        <p><label><input type="checkbox" /> Option 4</label></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

```
    $('.checkAll').on('click',function(){
        $('.checkboxes').prop('checked',$(this).prop("checked"));
    });`
```

Class `.checkAll` is a checkbox which controls the bulk action

Answer (score 4):

```html
 $(document).on('change', '.check-all', function () {
   if($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('.check-box').prop('checked', true)
   }else {
      $('.check-box').prop('checked', false);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to uncheck all the checkboxes on a page, the easiest way is like this:

```js
$('[type=checkbox]').prop("checked", false);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Best Solution here**
[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rupakdas85/nnwupsck/)

```
$("#checkAll").change(function () {
    $("input:checkbox.cb-element").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
});
$(".cb-element").change(function () {
        _tot = $(".cb-element").length                        
        _tot_checked = $(".cb-element:checked").length;

        if(_tot != _tot_checked){
            $("#checkAll").prop('checked',false);
        }
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/> ALL

<br />

<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(".checkAll").click(function() {
    if("checkall" === $(this).val()) {
         $(".cb-element").attr('checked', true);
         $(this).val("uncheckall"); //change button text
    }
    else if("uncheckall" === $(this).val()) {
         $(".cb-element").attr('checked', false);
         $(this).val("checkall"); //change button text
    }
});
```

Comment: I've tried your script, but no luck. Can you please see this if i have implemented correctly or not..? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfx/UZtSx/)

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self-promotion: [there's a jQuery plugin for that](http://mjball.github.com/jQuery-CheckAll/).

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="myform">
    <div><input type="checkbox" id="checkall"> <label for="checkall"> Check all</label></div>
    <fieldset id="slaves">
        <div><label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label></div>
        <div><label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label></div>
        <div><label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label></div>
        <div><label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label></div>
        <div><label><input type="checkbox"> Checkbox</label></div>
    </fieldset>
</form>​
```

JS:

```
$('#checkall').checkAll('#slaves input:checkbox', {
    reportTo: function () {
        var prefix = this.prop('checked') ? 'un' : '';
        this.next().text(prefix + 'check all');
    }
});​
```

...and you're done.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NrM2P

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" onclick="$('input[type=checkbox][class=cb-element]').attr('checked',this.checked)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this.checked` to verify the current state of the checkbox,

```
$('.checkAll').change(function(){
    var state = this.checked; //checked ? - true else false

    state ? $(':checkbox').prop('checked',true) : $(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);

    //change text
    state ? $(this).next('b').text('Uncheck All') : $(this).next('b').text('Check All')
});
```

```js
$('.checkAll').change(function(){
    var state = this.checked;
    state? $(':checkbox').prop('checked',true):$(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
    state? $(this).next('b').text('Uncheck All') :$(this).next('b').text('Check All')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <input type="checkbox" class="checkAll" /> <b>Check All</b>

   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to check/uncheck all checkboxes

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#check_uncheck").change(function() {
        if ($("#check_uncheck:checked").length) {
            $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
        } else {
            $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked", false);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck" /> Check All/Uncheck All
<br/>
<br/>
<div class="checkboxes">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 1
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 2
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 3
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 4
</div>
```

Try this [Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/imail2pankaj/cq10enkh/)

There is also another short way to do this, checkout below example. In this example check/uncheck all checkbox is checked or not if checked then all wiil be checked and if not all will be uncheck

```js
$("#check_uncheck").change(function() {
    $(".checkboxes input:checkbox").prop("checked",$(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" name="check_uncheck" id="check_uncheck" /> Check All/Uncheck All
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div class="checkboxes">
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 1
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 2
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 3
        <br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="check" id="check" /> Check Box 4
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        // Check All
        $('.checkall').click(function () {          
            $(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);
        });
        // Uncheck All
        $('.uncheckall').click(function () {            
            $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but, I noticed most people are using a checkbox. The accepted answer uses a button, but cannot work with several buttons (ex. one at top of page one at bottom). So here is a modification that does both.

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="check-box-machine my-button-style">Check All</a>
```

jQuery

```
var ischecked = false;
$(".check-box-machine").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ischecked == false) {
        $("input:checkbox").attr("checked","checked");
        $(".check-box-machine").html("Uncheck All");
        ischecked = true;
    } else {
        $("input:checkbox").removeAttr("checked");
        $(".check-box-machine").html("Check All");
        ischecked = false;
    }
});
```

This will allow you to have as many buttons as you would like with changing text and checkbox values. I included an `e.preventDefault()` call because this will stop the page from jumping to the top due to the `href="#"` part.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
    $('input#check_all').change(function () {
        $("input[name='input_ids[]']").prop('checked', $(this).prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are discouraged, because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link, which is used to check and uncheck the parent checkbox and all the child checkboxes are getting selected and deselected.

[jquery check uncheck all checkboxes Using Jquery **With Demo**](http://thedevelopertips.com/JQuery/JQuery/SelectDeselect-AllCheckBoxes.aspx?id=47)

```
$(function () {
        $("#select-all").on("click", function () {
            var all = $(this);
            $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                $(this).prop("checked", all.prop("checked"));
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(checked,total_boxes){ 
         for ( i=0 ; i < total_boxes ; i++ ){ 
           if (checked){   
             document.forms[0].checkBox[i].checked=true; 
            }else{  
             document.forms[0].checkBox[i].checked=false; 
            } 
        }   
    } 
</script>
    <body>
        <FORM> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >one<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >two<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >three<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >four<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >five<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >six<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >seven<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >eight<br> 
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >nine<br>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox" >ten<br>  s
            <input type=button name="CheckAll" value="Select_All" onClick="myFunction(true,10)"> 
            <input type=button name="UnCheckAll" value="UnCheck All Boxes" onClick="myFunction(false,10)"> 
        </FORM> 
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

add this in your code block, or even click of your button

```
$('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`removeAttr()` no longer works in later versions of jquery.
You can use the `prop()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').click(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Check All with uncheck/check controller if all items is/isnt checked

JS:

> e = checkbox id t= checkbox (item) class n= checkbox check all class

```
function checkAll(e,t,n){jQuery("#"+e).click(function(e){if(this.checked){jQuery("."+t).each(function(){this.checked=true;jQuery("."+n).each(function(){this.checked=true})})}else{jQuery("."+t).each(function(){this.checked=false;jQuery("."+n).each(function(){this.checked=false})})}});jQuery("."+t).click(function(e){var r=jQuery("."+t).length;var i=0;var s=0;jQuery("."+t).each(function(){if(this.checked==true){i++}if(this.checked==false){s++}});if(r==i){jQuery("."+n).each(function(){this.checked=true})}if(i<r){jQuery("."+n).each(function(){this.checked=false})}})}
```

HTML:

> Check ALL controle class : chkall_ctrl

```
<input type="checkbox"name="chkall" id="chkall_up" class="chkall_ctrl"/>
<br/>
1.<input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chkall" name="chk[]" id="chk1"/><br/>
2.<input type="checkbox" value="2" class="chkall" name="chk[]" id="chk2"/><br/>
3.<input type="checkbox" value="3" class="chkall" name="chk[]" id="chk3"/><br/>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox"name="chkall" id="chkall_down" class="chkall_ctrl"/>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
  checkAll('chkall_up','chkall','chkall_ctrl');
  checkAll('chkall_down','chkall','chkall_ctrl');
});
 </script>
```