# JS in .tpl file does not get compiled

Tags: php, jquery, smarty

I have the following code inside my .tpl file (I am using the [Smarty template engine](http://www.smarty.net/about_smarty) for my project).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all');
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
</script>

<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />

   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

However, in the final compiled php code, the JS function doesn't appear, as a result of which the toggle ("check all") button I want to create doesn't work. The final compiled php code, as seen in the browser looks like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
          $(document).ready(function(),function())
})
</script>

<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />

   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  1
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  2
   <input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" /> Checkbox  3
```

I am new to using both jQuery and Smarty. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The jQuery function has been discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229023/jquery-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-a-button).

**EDIT** **: I have put the JS inside {literal} and {/literal} and I can now see the JS function in the finally compiled php code. However, the JS function still does not respond! Why might that be?**

Comment: Shouldn't you be wrapping js in `{literal}...{/literal}`? Just search "using javascript in smarty templates" in Google...

Answer (score 2):

with smarty, and JS you add needs to be wrapped with `{literal}` and `{/literal}` so that smarty knows not to interpret the "{}" tags in the javascript as normal rather than as smarty normally interprets those tags

Comment: I have put the JS inside {literal} and {/literal} and I can now see the JS function in the finally compiled php code. However, the JS function still does not respond! Why might that be?

Comment: in the code about you are missing a ";" at the end of the script. does that help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I did paste all the code (as shown above) in a single php file, and that worked well. However, it doesn't work in .tpl file, even after all the edits.

Comment: In between the <script> and </script> tags. Also outside them. Both do the same thing for my code since the <script> tags have no Smarty variables in them. Also, does JSFiddle have an option to test Smarty templates? Because like I said, the whole things ran in a single php file when I ran it. It's the .tpl file that is causing problems.

Comment: You can't use smarty within a fiddle, but anything between the literal tags should act like smarty isn't involved. i do almost all of my work with smart and have never has this issue. is the script in the head tag?

Comment: No. It isn't in the head tag. I do get your point about the literal tags and that is why the fiddle you tried, and the single php file I tried work. But the problem with the .tpl file doesn't make sense to me either.

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting your JS in separate file and linking to it. Smarty uses `{` and `}` as special characters.