# button that will uncheck all checkboxes?

Tags: jquery, cookies, checkbox

I have a checkboxes that are being stored in a cookie.

Here is the jquery code:

```
//JQuery that will set the checkbox in it's current state
 $("#checkAll").on("change", function() {
    $(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
  });

  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    var checkboxValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      checkboxValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });
    $.cookie('checkboxValues', checkboxValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  });

  function repopulateCheckboxes(){
    var checkboxValues = $.cookie('checkboxValues');
    if(checkboxValues){
      Object.keys(checkboxValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = checkboxValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });
    }
  }

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateCheckboxes();
```

The code above works perfectly but when I try to use a button to uncheck them it does not uncheck at all.

Here is the function that I used:

```
 $("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
   $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked',false);
});
```

What should I do? could somebody help me.

Comment: Do you know if the click callback is even firing? Are some of the checkboxes clearing, but not all of them?

Comment: Checkboxes are clearing but after an refresh to the page it goes back to being checked.

Comment: then on page load clear your cookie

Comment: A page refresh will result in a call to `repopulateCheckboxes()`. Assuming that function works as expected, of course the checkbox states will be restored!

Comment: How do you workaround that?

Comment: yep but i hope you give more details into it so if other people will look upon this, they will have a better idea.

Comment: This has been explained here in detail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229023/jquery-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-a-button

Answer (score 1):

Give all checkboxes a class such as myclass. Then using jQuery.

Remove your cookie in `document.ready` function

```
 $.cookie("checkboxValues", null);//checkboxValues is the name of your cookie
```

For jQuery 1.6+

```
$("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
   $('input:checkbox:checked.myclass').prop('checked',false);
});
```

for jquery 1.5-

```
$("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
   $('input:checkbox:checked.myclass').attr('checked',false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
   $('input:checkbox.class').prop('checked',false);
});
```

or this if not have common class

```
 $("#UncheckAll").click(function(){
   $(':checkbox').prop('checked',false);
});
```