# Changing the columns displayed in a table with checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onclick

I have a table (in practice a grid) that can display a set of columns and the user can select the columns to display with a checkbox list. I had to insert a Check All/Uncheck All button.

```
$('#CheckUncheck').toggle(function(){
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked')
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").trigger('click');
    $(this).val('Check All')
},function(){
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('click');
    $(this).val('Uncheck all');        
});
```

Now when I click the Uncheck All button for the first time, the boxes are not getting unchecked but works normally after that. I have attached a Fiddle for a better understanding.

What am I doing wrong?
Also, am I triggering the change function in a valid manner?

**JSFiddle**: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/7/)

Comment: do you want this ... http://jsfiddle.net/moslake7020/mxdL1xwn/

Comment: In your fiddle, you have fixed the checking/unchecking of the checkbox but if you notice, the button's name doesn't change the first time you click the button. So your fix also ends up like my original code.

Comment: ok will come to u with... more improve ment.../.

Comment: Can you also figure out what's wrong with the click function?

Comment: just check now...  http://jsfiddle.net/moslake7020/mxdL1xwn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/9/)
 You are changing the checked attribute then triggering the click event that causing revert of your changing checked attribute

```
 $('#CheckUncheck').toggle(function(){
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked')//chk box unchecked
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").trigger('click');//chk box checked
    $(this).val('Check All')
},function(){
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('click');//same here first check by change in attribute then unchecked by triggering click event
    $(this).val('Uncheck all');        
});
```

try this--
firstly fire click event and after that change the ckecked value

```
 $('#CheckUncheck').toggle(function(){
 $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").trigger('click').removeAttr('checked')            
        $(this).val('Check All')
    },function(){
        $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").trigger('click').attr('checked', 'checked');
        $(this).val('Uncheck all');        
    });
```

Here's your link of expected result with fixed click function

http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/17/

Comment: I tried your solution. It works at first but then the checkbox is not responding: http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/10/

Comment: Oh thanks man! Can you also find what's wrong with my click function :(

Comment: In the original fiddle!

Comment: Your code cleared the bug but the click behaviour was not favourable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/14/ heres the final solution,use change event instead :)

Comment: Thank you for your time @vikrant! But changing the individual checkboxes are not hiding the respective cells. :( Good effort though!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59917/discussion-between-nooblord-and-vikrant-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the uncheck to check. 
Try this code. I've tested it with your code. Here's your [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/12/)

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#CheckUncheck:button').toggle(function(){ 
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all'); 
        },function(){
              $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).val('uncheck all')      
        })
    });
```

For checking if value is selected or not you can use prop like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbaq66ev/19/).

```
   $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    var cbValue = "#"+$(this).val();
          if ($(this).prop('checked')==true){ 
           $(cbValue).show();
          }else{
           $(cbValue).hide();
          }
});
```

Comment: under the #CheckUncheck, I have a number of buttons. So I don't think I can use #CheckUncheck:button as a selector.

Comment: you can only use #CheckUncheck like what did you do in your demo fiddle. I've updated the link demo for you to see.

Comment: Phew that works. Can you see my click function too? I think that's more important.

Comment: I see you have taken off the click function altogether. I know it works without the click function. I wanted to have the click function and still wanted it to work. Without click function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229023/jquery-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-a-button

Comment: what do you mean with you click function to div?  you want to check a checkbox and hide/show  the value of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the    **[NEW DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/moslake7020/mxdL1xwn/1/)**  look at it.... Is this you want... But for it you have to see wheather the checkvboxes are by default checked or not...

i have changed your htmml little just added data-id attribute to button

```
<div id="ButtonDiv">
  <input type="button" id="CheckUncheck" data-id="uncheck" value="Uncheck All"/>
```

```
<div id="CheckBoxDiv">
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1"  value="Cell1" /> Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" id="cb2"  value="Cell2" /> Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" id="cb3" checked="checked" value="Cell3" /> Checkbox 3
<input type="checkbox" id="cb4" checked="checked" value="Cell4" /> Checkbox 4
</div>

<div>
<table id="table">
    <tr id="row">
        <td id="Cell1">1</td>
        <td id="Cell2">2</td>
        <td id="Cell3">3</td>
        <td id="Cell4">4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

And new javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
alert($("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").length+'========'+$("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']:checked").length);

if($("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").length == $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']:checked").length)
{
    $('#CheckUncheck').attr('Value','Uncheck All');
     $('#CheckUncheck').attr('data-id','uncheck');
}
else
{
    $('#CheckUncheck').attr('Value','Check All');
     $('#CheckUncheck').attr('data-id','check');
}

$("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").click(function () {
    var cbValue = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $(cbValue).show();
        }
        else {
            $(cbValue).hide();
        }
});

$('#CheckUncheck').click(function(){

   if( $('#CheckUncheck').attr('data-id') == "check")
   {     


    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").removeAttr('checked');
    $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").trigger('click');

    $(this).val('Uncheck All');  
    $(this).attr('data-id','uncheck');



    }
    else
    {           

   $("#CheckBoxDiv input[type='checkbox']").attr('checked','checked').trigger('click');


    $(this).val('Check All');
    $(this).attr('data-id','check');
    }


});


});
```

It is working ... check the demo.... in given link

Comment: While clicking the first time, you're button's text doesn't change to "Check All".