# Adding checkall checkbox in first column in DataTable

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, datatables-1.10

How can I add checkbox with ability to 'check-all' and single check in first column of dataTable.. column which doesn't came from server-side script?
So far I was able to put only at the end of table one button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "response.php", 

    "aoColumnDefs": [
      {
        "aTargets": [7],
        "mData": null,
        "mRender": function (data, type, full) {
          return '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=edit.php?id=' + full[0] + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>';
        }             
      }]
  });
});
```

and the html part

```html
<table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>№</th>
      <th>Program</th>
      <th>Subject</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>                              
      <th>Keywords</th> 
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery check uncheck all checkboxes with a button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229023/jquery-check-uncheck-all-checkboxes-with-a-button)

Comment: It is not duplicate. I'm using `dataTables`.. it is different

Comment: See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/

Comment: @MoshFeu thank's but I have tried this. The problem with this is that I can't put both columns `one at front` and `one at the end`... So far I was succeed with only one custom column

Comment: Why not? https://jsfiddle.net/7e69e2ux/1/

Comment: I want to preserve my last column which is on `js` on my question. But somehow they can't work together.. `eturn '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href=edit.php?id=' + full[0] + '>' + 'Edit' + '</a>';`

Comment: So first column `checkbox` last column `edit button` between them is the server-side data that is coming.