# Bokeh widget callback to select all checkboxes

Tags: python, bokeh

I have run into a couple problems in trying to setup a Bokeh CheckboxGroup widget. The Checkbox group it self is large (50 states) and I would like to initialize the selection as all active.

Also (and more importantly) since this group is intended to be highly interactive, I would like to add buttons to "Select All" and "Clear All".  I understand that I will need some callback mechanism to do this, but after searching the examples, documentation and stackoverflow, was not able to figure out just how.  I include a simplified version of my code below.  My preference is to use the standard widget Callback rather than the JS callback.

Any help appreciated!

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, output_file
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Callback 

output_file("states.html", title="states")

states = ["Alabama", "Alaska ", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", \
        "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", \
        "Hawaii", "Idaho ", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", \
        "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", \
        "Michigan ", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana",\
        "Nebraska", "Nevada ", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",\
        "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", \
        "Ohio", "Oklahoma","Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", \
        "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah",\
        "Vermont", "Virginia","Washington", "West Virginia", \
        "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]

states = CheckboxGroup(
        labels = states,
        active=[0,1])

select_all = Button(label="select all")
# need some help here

group = widgetbox(select_all, states)

layout = row(group)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "states"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic function of the Bokeh server is to keep all Bokeh objects in sync on both the Python and JS sides. The `active` property of the `CheckboxGroup` specifies which boxed are checked, at all times, not just initialization. So to check all the boxes, you only need to set it appropriately in the callback:

```
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc, output_file
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, CheckboxGroup
from bokeh.layouts import widgetbox, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Callback

output_file("states.html", title="states")

states_list = ["Alabama", "Alaska ", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", \
        "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", \
        "Hawaii", "Idaho ", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", \
        "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", \
        "Michigan ", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana",\
        "Nebraska", "Nevada ", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey",\
        "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", \
        "Ohio", "Oklahoma","Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", \
        "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah",\
        "Vermont", "Virginia","Washington", "West Virginia", \
        "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"]

states = CheckboxGroup(
        labels = states_list,
        active=[0,1])

select_all = Button(label="select all")

def update():
    states.active = list(range(len(states_list)))
select_all.on_click(update)

group = widgetbox(select_all, states)

layout = row(group)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
curdoc().title = "states"
```

Comment: Great! If you could mark the answer as correct that would be appreciated.

Comment: I just checked that it's working fine for me with `0.12.5` if you can isolate a reproducible environment where there is a problem,  I'd suggest a GH issue.

Comment: @bigreddot I'm on Python `2.7.12` with bokeh `0.12.5` (on Windows 10). Exactly the same code you've provided. What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @bigreddot Also, I tried it on Chrome and Firefox. (Ha! Just realized you're the `bokeh` repository owner :) )

Comment: Py 3.6 on OSX. I'd definitely suggest a GH issue with this info then, so that it doesn't get lost or forgotten.

Comment: Would a variation of this work on DataTables? So instead of "states.active" for check boxes, I would use "states.selected = list_of_indices" if states were instead a DataTable?

Comment: You'd need to set the selection on the underlying column data source, which follows a particular format. Worth a new question.